# C preprocessor: Is there any way to expand the name of a macro inside itself

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I would like to have a macro that prints it's own name (among other things), but I can't find a way to expand the macros' name in the macro itself. Basically, I want the equivalent of `__FUNCTION__` for a macro name.

For example:

```
#define F(a, b, c) do { \
   printf("%s: %s,%s,%s\n", __MACRO__, #a, #b, #c); \
   c = a+b; b=a; \
} while(0)

F(x,y,z);
```

I would like this to print "F: x,y,z" when called.

---

This is indeed an XY problem.

Here is really what I'm trying to do: Soft linking symbols from a library using dlopen and dlsyms.

In order to do so the typical way i know of is:
1) Include the headers from the library.
2) Declare a variable of the type of the function you are trying to import
3) Initialize said variable with a call to dlsym
4) The call the actual function through that variable instead of calling the symbol directly.

When you have many such function to soft link, it becomes very repetitive, so macro can help.

For an full fledge example of that, see here: https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/platform/mac/SoftLinking.h

The problem in that example and others is that you still need to manually copy the parameters list for each the functions you want to soft link.
I'm trying to improve on that, and was experimenting with macro tricks, one of which would have been helped by being able to answer my initial question.

--

Beside my soft linking issues, there are other situation where this could be useful. For example for debugging purpose, one might want to print some diagnostic information before or after every call to certain functions. One could do so by overriding functions names with macros:

```
#define funcA(...) \
printf("Before call to %s:%d - %d\n", #funcA, __LINE__, g_count); \
funcA(__VA_ARGS__) \
printf("After call to %s:%d - %d\n", #funcA, __LINE__, g_count);
```

This works well enough but if I want to do this for a bunch of function, I have to copy that macro and change funcA to funcB 4 times for each new macro. I'd rather copy it and just change the name of the macros, without having to change what's inside.

I can optimize the above by defining an internal macro p, similar to what Basile suggested:

```
#define funcA(...) WRAP(funcA, __VA_ARGS__)
```

But that's still means I need to change funcA to the new function name twice every time I copy the macro for another function.

Comment: Why do you wish to make you code unreadable and more difficult to debug? Why does some people love the pre-proccessor.  It has its place for doing simple stuff.

Comment: Well, that example is too simple. In my actual use case, the 'printf' would actually be embedded in another macros like this `#define P(f, ...) printf("%s%s\n", f, __VA_ARGS__)`

Comment: @EdHeal I'm actually trying to avoid having to copy paste a pattern a bunch of times.

Comment: Macros are terrible to debug. They obfuscate the code. They do not have the luxury of the type mechanism that the compiler enjoys. Why use them?

Comment: Thanks for the advice @EdHeal, but that would not help in this case.

Comment: It really looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). **Why do you ask?** Please **edit your question** to improve it. Show the actual code which makes you want such a feature

Comment: What is the actual library you want to soft link? How many public symbols does it have?

Comment: It's not a public library. I have probably 20 or so symbols I need. But while researching this I've encountered a project in a similar situation but with 200 symbols. In that case they ended up with a solution involving assembly hacks, so architecture specific.

Answer (score 2):

Read more about the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor). Read the documentation of [GNU cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/). Notice its [stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) and [concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) abilities.

Perhaps going thru some extra internal macro might help you, so you might have a public macro like

```
 #define FOO(X,Y,Z) PRIVATE_FOO(FOO,X,Y,Z)
```

with another `PRIVATE_FOO` macro doing stringification tricks on its first argument, maybe

```
#define PRIVATE_FOO(Mac,X,Y,Z) do { \
 printf("%s: %s,%s,%s\n", #Mac, #X, #Y, #Z); \
 Z = X+Y; Y=X; \
} while(0)
```

Perhaps the C preprocessor is not adequate for your task. You could generate some C code with some other tool (perhaps the [GPP](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP) preprocessor, or perhaps a simple `awk` or `python` script, or perhaps some real program; you'll need to change your build process, e.g. your `Makefile`, to handle that). You could customize your [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) if you need that. Since we don't know your actual motivations, we cannot help more.

I cannot help more, unless you motivate and clarify your question.

Your soft linking issue needs simply to use some [weak symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol). It is probably unrelated to C preprocessing.

Comment: No weak symbols, or weak linking is a different problem than soft linking, at least on my platform (OS X). In particular, when soft-linking (as I described above) you don't need to have the library you are soft linking at build time, while you still need it when weak linking.

Comment: Regarding your comment about internal macros, this is indeed what I'm trying to use, and this is why I would like to get the macro name.